# Angular event listener $on is not recognised by jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I added event broadcasting and emiting and now jasmine fails on loading the elements.

The controller function, who is receives events and i want to test looks like this

```
    function Tree(scope, $http, dataservice, Block, events) {

    var $scope = scope;
    init();
    function init(){
        // React to global events
        $scope.$on(events.reloadOnNewData, onNewData);
    }
```

In Jasmine i have following code in the unit-test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _ParameterList_) {
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
    controller = $controller('Tree', {$scope: $scope});
}));
```

And in karma conf i usind flowing angular mpdules

```
'./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        './bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        './bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        './bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        './bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
```

When i run the test i get

```
    TypeError: $scope.$on is not a function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to instantiate rootScope and pass that in controller then it'll not show this error.

```
  var $scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _ParameterList_,$rootScope) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $scope =  $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        controller = $controller('Tree', {$scope: $scope});
    }));
```

Comment: but now the scope is changed by rootscope, so i get errors if any variables rely on the local scope like $scope.selectedItem = {}

Comment: @Sonne no it's not - `$rootScope.$new()` creates a new scope that prototypically inherits *from* `$rootScope`, however this is the same mechanism that (nearly) all scopes in Angular are created anyway.

Answer (score 2):

define i in this way .

```
var scope;
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _ParameterList_,$rootScope) {

    $controller = _$controller_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    controller = $controller('Tree', {$scope: scope});
}));
```